# Button click event fires only once

Tags: jquery, jqxgrid

**This is the custom button column definition in the qxgrid**

```
{ text: 'Actions', cellsrenderer: function (row, column, value) 
 {
    var viewType = $("#divManageViewGrid").jqxGrid('getcellvalue', row, 'VIEW_TYPE');
     if (viewType == "Shared") {
       return '<input type="button" class="button-link" id="btnRemove" value="Remove"/>';
                         }
    return '<input type="button" class="button-link-delete"  value="Delete"/>';
               }
        } column definition
```

**This is the button click event which fires only once**

```
 $(document).on(‘click’, “.button-link”, function () 
 {
   //open popup
    var row = $(“#divManageViewGrid”).jqxGrid(‘getselectedrowindex’);
    id = $(“#divManageViewGrid”).jqxGrid(‘getrowid’, row);
    $("#popupWindow").jqxWindow('show');
  });
```

the button click event fires only once can any one help me on this even though i have used "on"

Comment: can you show me your HTML ?

Comment: Do you want the click event to fire for both buttons, or is the problem that it only fires once for the 'Remove' button?

Comment: basically i have used jqxgrid and i have included a column definition..yes same event should be fired for both remove and delete button click and moreover it opens a popup or jqxwindow if i comment the popup open code it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen your HTML but may be the following step can resolve your problem:

Make sure that at any point of time you don't have two controls(Dynamically generated) with same ID in your DOM(Document object model, including your popup html). This can really cause a problem.

Comment: i am binding the class name of the button using on method but as soon as i execute a code to open a popup id = $(“#divManageViewGrid”).jqxGrid(‘getrowid’, row);
    $("#popupWindow").jqxWindow('show'); it doesnt fire click event of that button is there a way to dynamically recreate button click using jquery